# Async DoInBackground Crashing under Listview

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I got some code of a fellow stackflower and for some reason, it's crashing my App, being new to Async, I don't have a lot of debugging experience. I'm trying to download data from via HttPost and then list the data in a simple listview. Anyway, here's the code and logcat:

code:

```
public class ChatService extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    List headlines;
    List links;
    String GotPass;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    String GotUname;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME ="MyPregs";
    private GetTask getTask;
    public ListView fList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getTask = new GetTask(); 
      getTask.execute();

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
    }

    public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List> 
    {
      @Override
      protected List doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return load();
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(List result) {


        fList.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
    }

    private List load() { 
      // get your data from http
      // add to your list, probably you can use model.
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        Bundle gotData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(gotData != null)
        {
            GotPass = gotData.getString("key!");
            GotUname = gotData.getString("key!!");
        }
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String username = settings.getString("key1", null);
        String password = settings.getString("key2", null);
         if(username.equals("irock97")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yaya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gta5news.com/login.php");

        try {
            // Add user name and password
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l ="";
            String nl ="";
            while ((l =in.readLine()) !=null) {
                sb.append(l + nl);  
            }
            in.close();
             data = sb.toString();

             ListView lv = getListView();
             lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            headlines.add(data);




            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

            setListAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return headlines;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString1(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }




    }
```

LogCat:

```
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService.load(ChatService.java:97)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService.access$0(ChatService.java:82)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService$GetTask.doInBackground(ChatService.java:71)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService$GetTask.doInBackground(ChatService.java:1)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-10 20:47:18.526: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You are calling Toast in load() function which is in DoInBackground. 
Toast messages touches UI thread which you can't do that.

This line makes it crash.
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yaya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Change you load function signature:
This is your function:
private List load() {

don't return a list, create a modal container and return it like:
private ReturnModel load() {

and create a modal like this, and set and get this modal:
and in your load function,fill this returnmodal, set passworderror true or false instead of toast message, and onpostexecute function, check password error and do your toast message there.




package com.nesim.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChatService extends ListActivity {
  String GotPass;
  String GotUname;
  public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPregs";
  private GetTask getTask;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getTask = new GetTask();
    getTask.execute();
  }

  public class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ReturnModel> {
    @Override
    protected ReturnModel doInBackground(Void... params) {
      return load();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ReturnModel result) {

      if(result.passworderror == true)
      {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      else
      {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yaya", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result.getheadlines());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
    }
  }

  private ReturnModel load() {
    ReturnModel returnModel = new ReturnModel();

    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;
    Bundle gotData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (gotData != null) {
      GotPass = gotData.getString("key!");
      GotUname = gotData.getString("key!!");
    }

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    String username = settings.getString("key1", null);
    String password = settings.getString("key2", null);
    // username = "irock97"; // unremark to test like you got username from prefs..
    if (username != null  && username.equals("irock97")) {
      returnModel.setPassworderror(false);
    }
    else 
    {
      returnModel.setPassworderror(true);
      return returnModel;
    }

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    /* login.php returns true if username and password is equal to saranga */
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gta5news.com/login.php");

    try {
      // Add user name and password
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

      // Execute HTTP Post Request
      Log.w("HttpPost", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
      HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
      String l = "";
      String nl = "";
      while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(l + nl);
      }
      in.close();
      data = sb.toString();


      List<String> headlines = new ArrayList<String>();
      headlines.add(data);
      returnModel.setheadlines(headlines);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnModel;
  }


  public class ReturnModel {
    private List<String> headlines;
    private boolean passworderror;

    public List<String> getheadlines() {
      return headlines;
    }

    public void setheadlines(List<String> headlines) {
      this.headlines = headlines;
    }

    public boolean getPassworderror() {
      return passworderror;
    }

    public void setPassworderror(boolean passworderror) {
      this.passworderror = passworderror;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It still crashes even when I remove those lines.

Comment: EDIT1: I see your updated comment, I still don't understand the code.

Comment: I tried to update again. basicaly create a simple container which includes your List and some other fields to keep like loginerror etc. fill and return that modal from load function to onpostexecute.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning; if it doesn't work, I'll re-write the Async again.

Comment: I created a test project and edited your code with my suggestions now. Check my latest code, It will work.

Comment: Thanks :) You've been a great help! Have a great day, sir.

Comment: Wow! I just tried it, works like a dream. Thanks so much, you've made my day, :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Call Looper.Prepare() in doInbackground()

Edit: Also make sure you run the Toast on the UI thread, as everyone else notes.

Comment: I just tried this and it still crashes. Should I update the thread with the new logcat?

Comment: If you added Looper.Prepare() and it still crashes, if it is a Thread error with creating vies, then follow what kailoon said and use the runOnUIThread() function as well.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you are trying to modify UI outside the UI thread. The error you are seeing is being caused by the `Toast.makeText()` calls. You can re-write it to:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText( /* etc */).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Toast.makeText` not in the main UI thread.

As it is written in the stack trace:

Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare().
Internally, Toast.makeText is creating handler for its own use.

If this is for test purposes, you should better use Log.v or similar.

If you want to really make Toasts, then try to use runOnUIThread(), or better:

> publishProgress(...);

and

> onProgressUpdate()

which are available from AsyncTasks.